# Computing the negative log likelihood with numpy

Tags: numpy, logistic-regression, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to implement only with Numpy the following formula for the negative log likelihood

[image: Negative log likelihood]

However I am getting two vastly different results between the sum formulation or the matrix formulation (in comment in the bellow code block).

```
def log_likelihood(y, tx, w):
s = 0

for i in range(len(y)):
    s += np.log(1+np.exp(tx[i,:].T@w))-y[i]*tx[i,:].T@w

return s
#return np.sum(np.log(1+np.exp(tx@w))-y@tx@w)
```

Any idea what's wrong with my matrix formulation?

Comment: You don't transpose in the second one.  Also, I'd have to look more closely, but do you want to transpose *before* you slice, not after?  `x[i].T` is going to be different than `x.T[i]`

Comment: @user3483203 What and why should I transpose exactly? I should have mentionned that tx is a matrix with rows x_1, ..., x_n.